# Unittests not working

Tags: python, python-unittest

I can't figure out why no tests are run using:
`python tests/quick_tests.py` and python unittest.

Here is the contents of the file:

```
import sys
import os
from App import app
import unittest
from App.helpers import *
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash
import requests
import pdb
import pickle
from App.models import *
import re
from httmock import all_requests, response, HTTMock, urlmatch
from mock_apis import *


class AppTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.app = app.test_client()
        app.config['WTF_CSRF_ENABLED'] = False


    def tearDown(self):
        del self.app

    def testhome(self):
        with app.app_context():
            r = self.app.get('/')
            self.assertEqual(r.status_code, 200)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Just results in:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

Please guide me. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def main(): 
   '''Run the unit test ''' 
   tester = unittest.main(exit=False)     
   sys.exit(0 if tester.result.wasSuccessful() else -1)

if __name__ == '__main__': 
   main()



__all__ = [ 
   'AppTestCase'
]
```

Comment: Still same result :/

Answer (score 0):

Burying through the files in my `App`, and commenting them out in binary search fashion seeing where unittests starts to break, I have found that removing a single `import ipdb` fixes the problem. I don't know what conclusion to draw from this other than: Unittest does not play nice with ipdb. Hopefully this post saves other peoples' time in the future.